# Replace one term in R with a list of terms so that I can create repeat a plot function R

Tags: r

I am trying to create a jitter boxplot in R, and want to create three of these boxplots- one plot for each of the objects in this list: CUL7, CUL8, FANCE. I want to find a way to repeat the code for CUL7 to make CUL8's boxplot, just switching out "CUL7" and inserting "CUL8", with FANCE working the same way.

This is what the code for one of the boxplots:

```
cul7_ind <- which(cnv_ge_plot[,1] == "CUL7")
ggplot(cnv_ge_plot[cul7_ind,], aes(source, fold.change)) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  geom_jitter() +
  ggtitle("CUL7 Expression Plot")
```

Comment: Do you want to loop? If it is only three plots, why not use copy & paste plus search & replace?

Comment: If the three objects are already in a list, just use `lapply` to repeat the plotting operations over the list's elements. It will return a list of plot objects that you can the print or save or whatever.

Answer (score 1):

Could you use just a for loop in the following manner:

```
> plotlist <- c('CUL7','CUL8','FANCE')
> for (currplot in plotlist) {
+   print(paste(currplot,"Expression Plot"))
+ }
[1] "CUL7 Expression Plot"
[1] "CUL8 Expression Plot"
[1] "FANCE Expression Plot"
```

This is not full example, but you may easily to adapt to your own purpose.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
# Load libraries
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

# My list of stuff
MyList <- list("CUL7", "CUL8", "FANCE")

# My plotting function
MyPlot <- function(x){
  ggplot(cnv_ge_plot %>% filter(.[1] == x), aes(source, fold.change)) +
    geom_boxplot() +
    geom_jitter() +
    ggtitle(paste(x, "Expression Plot", sep = " "))
}

# List of gpplot2 objects
MyPlotList <- lapply(MyList, MyPlot)
```